# series of $\sum e^{i \lambda n}/(n+\alpha)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there any analytical or approximate results of the series

> $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{e^{i \lambda n}}{(n+\alpha)}$$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $|\alpha|<1$ is real, $i^2=-1$.

Comment: I would multiply by $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ and then take the derivative.

Comment: is this a summation over $n$? and what is $i$?

Comment: Your series is infinite because of $e^{i2\pi n}=1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n\ \geq\ 0}\ldots = \,\mathrm{L}\left({\lambda \over 2\pi},\alpha,1\right)$. $\,\mathrm{L}$ is the [Lerch Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

We write it as a function:

$$f(z,\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n+\alpha}$$

We then note that:

$$\frac1{n+\alpha}=\int_0^\infty e^{-(n+\alpha)x}~\mathrm dx$$

And likewise,

$$\begin{align}f(z,\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(ze^{-x})^n~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{ze^{-\alpha x}}{e^x-z}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_1^\infty\frac{z}{x^{1+\alpha}(x-z)}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{zx^\alpha}{1-zx}~\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Which holds when $\Re(\alpha)>-1$.  The last integral may easily be approximated by its Riemann sum, Taylor expansion, etc.

Assuming $\Re(\alpha)>0$

$$\begin{align}f(z,\alpha)&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{zn^\alpha}{N^{\alpha+1}-znN^\alpha}\\&=\frac{2^{1-\alpha}z}{2-z}+\frac{2^{1-\alpha}(\alpha^2(z-2)^2-\alpha(3z^2-8z+4)+2z^2)}{(2-z)^3}+\dots\end{align}$$

Source of taylor expansion: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+of+x%5Ea+%2F(1-bx)+at+x%3D1%2F2)

Comment: very interesting integral representation: looks it is valid also for $|z|=1$, is it?

Comment: @GCab Valid for any $z\notin[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: When $|z|>1, it's equal to the analytic extension of the given series.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$S(\lambda) =\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{e^{i\lambda n}}{n+\alpha} $$
$$e^{i\lambda\alpha }\cdot S(\lambda) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{e^{i\lambda(n+\alpha)}}{n+\alpha} $$

Now, take derivative on both sides wrt $\lambda$ we get
$$e^{i\lambda\alpha }\frac{dS}{d\lambda} + {i\alpha e^{i\lambda\alpha}S(\lambda)} =
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{i(n+\alpha)e^{i\lambda(n+\alpha)}}{n+\alpha} $$

$$e^{i\lambda\alpha }\frac{dS}{d\lambda} + {i\alpha e^{i\lambda\alpha}S(\lambda)} = 
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ie^{i\lambda(n+\alpha)} $$
Divide throughout by $i \cdot e^{i\lambda\alpha}$,
$$-i\frac{dS}{d\lambda} + \alpha{S(\lambda)} = 
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} e^{in} $$
$${\alpha S(\lambda)} = i\frac{dS}{d\lambda} +  
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} e^{in} $$ 
Now calculating $\frac{dS}{d\lambda}$ explicitly from the initial relation we get 
$$\frac{dS}{d\lambda} = i \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{e^{i\lambda n}}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}} $$ 
Substituting this in the previous relation we get,
$${\alpha S(\lambda)} =   
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} e^{in}  -\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{e^{i\lambda n}}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}}  $$

I don't know how to proceed after this. The sum on the left diverges and I can't really say anything about the sum on right. This is not really an answer but this was too long for a comment. Sorry.

Thanks to @GCab for pointing out an error in the previous version of this answer.

Comment: Sorry, but $S'(\alpha)$ is not convergent (only somehow oscillating) because it has no null sequence.

Comment: Are you saying that my usage of the formula of thegeometric series is incorrect there?

Comment: Let's wait if the OP is still interested in his question.

Comment: Sorry for my incorret copy of the question. Tanks for your concern about the question. Fortunately, @Aditya Kumar understands what i want to say. Would you mind give more details of the derivative (equation 2 to 3 in your answer)?

Comment: @AdityaKumar: nice algebraical exercise, apart from the conclusion "..since $|\alpha|<1$ then $S(\alpha) \approx \cdots$ which does not make sense: you are invited to delete it

Comment: @GCab, thank you for pointing that out. I am not really sure how to go about it. I am leaving it with a note. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: as for leaving it, for your reputation first, and for that of this site, you are definitely invited to cancel it. Just finish with the fact that you have provided a differential equation for $S$. As for ideas, see my answer.

Comment: Noted and corrected. Thank your for your suggestion :)

Comment: appreciate you understood the spirit of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {{{\exp \left( {i2\pi \lambda n} \right)} \over {\left( {n + \alpha } \right)^{\,s} }}}  =  - {1 \over {\alpha ^{\,s} }} + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\exp \left( {i2\pi \lambda n} \right)} \over {\left( {n + \alpha } \right)^{\,s} }}}  = L(\lambda ,\alpha ,s) - {1 \over {\alpha ^{\,s} }}
$$
where $L(\lambda ,\alpha ,s) $ is by definition the [Lerch-zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function),
connected with the [Lerch-Transcendent Function](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi).

These functions are analytical over the whole $\mathbb {C}^3$ , but for the values you want to calculate them
the formula above does not converge, and analytical continuation shall be used.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My question is really a special case of Lerch-zeta function for the case of $s=1$ and $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ are all reals. Could you give me more detailed introduction (books or reviews) about the special condition i met ? Thank you very much. @G Gab

Comment: @Guanghong: I am not a specialist in this field: I would suggest that you recast your question making explicit reference that you are looking for the Lerch-zeta function values  for $s=1$.

Comment: For $\lambda\in(0,2\pi)$, $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{i\lambda n}}{n+\alpha}\right|<\infty$$Indeed, it does converge, as one can see by Dirichlet's test (quite straight-forwardly)